# Has there been a study done in tuning hyper-parameters for off-policy reinforcement learning?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, dqn, off-policy-methods

I am interested in learning about hyper-parameter tuning for off-policy reinforcement learning (specifically DQN). Could someone point me to papers published or empirical observations in this area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and we can do it in a similar way we normally perform hyper-param optimization. See [this paper from Google](https://deepai.org/publication/online-hyper-parameter-tuning-in-off-policy-learning-via-evolutionary-strategies)

In this framework we can also attempt to jerry-rig some of our classic algorithmic tuning techniques with better or worse success depending on the context.